# Updating OpenGL support (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Mesa 12.0.6)

Tags: 16.04, opengl, mesa

I'm not an expert and am looking for troubleshooting guidance.

I'm pretty sure my GPU hardware supports OpenGL 4.3, but I'm actually just looking for support up to 4.1 since I have Mesa 12.0.6 installed.

`glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` returns:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
```

I think I have the radeon driver installed. `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` returns:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Not sure where to proceed from here.  My understanding is that I'm using the recommended graphics driver for 16.04 LTS, and Mesa 12.0.6 should support up to 4.3, but I'm only getting 3.0 at the moment.  How can I get this up to at least 4.1?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

I should probably mention I'd like to develop software that will run on an up-to-date out-of-the-box 16.04 LTS install, and I'd rather not request a prospective user update their kernel if necessary.  I'll live with OpenGL 3.0 if the current linux kernel doesn't support anything higher.

That said, I see that we can soon expect kernel 4.8 for the 16.04.2 release, so maybe this problem will be fixed then.

Thanks.

Comment: First update your system by `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. This will install mesa 12.0.6.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same result.  I'll update my question to reflect current versions.

Comment: And you probably need the 4.8 kernel to support even 4.5.

Comment: Run `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04` and reboot.

Comment: And also `llvm-3.9` is required to get OpenGL 4.5.

Comment: I guess you will need Ubuntu 16.10 if this does not work.

Comment: None of this will work because the radeon driver does not support newer versions of OpenGL on this card yet. https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#note_19 If you blacklist the _radeon_ driver and can get _amdgpu_ working with your card, then maybe you can have newer GL support.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem, although my hardware supports higher versions it does not update.
If you want to run programs with a higher version of openGL you can try using the below command as found in the [forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2382699)
`MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=450 <programname>`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/a/691693/712104
Use `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to get all OpenGL information and take a look at the `OpenGL core profile` - this will give you the actual OpenGL version.